# Glide and ImageView gapless

Tags: android, imageview

I want to load images into imageView in android using glide in gapless manner .currently i am able to change the in image using glide but during change of image black screen is shown usually(1/2 second) . i want to make it gapless.i am facing issue  in doing so
following is my code .

```
                      **new CountDownTimer(1000000, 4000) { // adjust 
              the milli seconds here
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
                       {
                            try {
                                if(azanmediacount.size() <=0)
                                {
                                }else
                                {
                                if(azan < azanmediacount.size())
                                {
                                Log.e("azan1232",    
            azanmediacount.get(azan));
                                File imgFile = new 
  
     
    File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
        "/images/" + azanmediacount.get(azan));
                                    Log.e("mybitmap1235", 
           String.valueOf(imgFile.exists()));
                                if (imgFile.exists()) {
                                    Animation animSlide = 
            AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                                            R.anim.exit_to_left
                                    );
          // Start the animation like this
                                    
        imageView.startAnimation(animSlide);
                                    
        //imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                                    
            Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                                            .load(new 
     
     
     
    File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() 
            + 
            "/images/" + azanmediacount.get(azan)))
                                            .into(imageView);
                                    azan = azan +1;
                                    if(azan ==azanmediacount.size())
                                    {
                                        azan = 0;
                                    }
                                }
                            }}}
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        public void onFinish() {
                          imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    }.start();**
```

how to remove gap between image change?

Comment: try placeholder show loading

Comment: i cannot use showloading .as  my requirments are gapless image exchange on digital signage